# Children who make a hideout out of an abandoned house and an evil teacher/being breaks in

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I heard this on tape as an audiobook when I was much younger. I have a feeling it had some fantasy elements, it was definitely a horror-ish story at the end, and not a short story either.

A small group of children, maybe 10-15 years of age, find an abandoned house and set it up as their den, using the fridge and putting sofas inside, etc. A teacher is hunting them down for some reason, and at the end he captures one of them as a "fanfare" (that's all I remember it saying) was playing on loop on a tape machine. They find out the tape machine was in the middle of an empty room upstairs and the man that was looking for them is standing outside the window. They throw something at him (maybe an apple) and knock him out. The next time they see him, he has a black eye.

It was a reasonably lighthearted story up until the disturbing ending.

EDIT: I was listening to it about a decade ago, so nothing newer than that. It was several hours long, maybe eight.

Any ideas at all would be appreciated, Google turns up nothing.

Comment: Not *Nightmare on Elm Street*?

Comment: No, it was nothing quite as drastic as that, more subtle.

Comment: Sounds vaguely like the first Boxcar Children book. Slight clarification question: what were the F/SF elements of the story?

Comment: It was more modern than Boxcar Children, there was a cassette tape player. There was a mystery/horror kind of aspect and questions as to whether the person chasing them exists. I suppose it's a bit of a longshot to call it fantasy

Comment: Sounds familiar. Did they find shards of broken glass in parking lot and think it was diamonds?

Comment: Oh! I think you might be onto something.

Comment: Okay, I don't remember the title, but I can provide you with some additional details that might help you get an answer.

Here's everything I remember. If it sounds right, feel free to edit it into your question:

It wasn't an abandoned house but an abandoned theater. The kids (I think it was 2 boys and a girl but I'm not sure) want to restore the theater and put on a play.

The main character is an aspiring writer and wants to write they play they perform. However they have never actually finished a story.

Comment: So they're trying to raise money. At one point they find a bunch of shards of glass in a parking lot. To test if it's a diamond, they use a shard to cut the glass of their bike mirror. Since it works, they assume it must be a real diamond and try to sell the shards to a pawn shop or something who informs them pretty much anything an cut glass and it's probably from someone's windshield.
I don't know what happens next or how it ends. Hopefully we're thinking of the same story, and that's enough to jog someone's memory.

Comment: John Bellairs's *The Doom of the Haunted Opera* (https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/805950.The_Doom_of_the_Haunted_Opera) keeps coming up in searches, but it doesn't look like they make the opera house a clubhouse.

Comment: It's not *The Doom of the Haunted Opera*. Totally different narrative.